# ViewFlipper animation in same Activity

Tags: android, animation, button, view

I have this screen.

[image: image1]

And want to convert it to this.

[image: image2]

I hope you understand what I am trying to do. Here is my xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/appBackground"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:weightSum="1"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:context="loginScreen.solution.example.com.loginScreen.WelcomeActivity">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="#CC5ec639"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Welcome"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                style="@style/TextView"
                android:ems="10"
                android:text="Name: "
                android:backgroundTint="@color/textboxTint"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                style="@style/TextView"
                android:ems="10"
                android:text="Email: "/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_phone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                style="@style/TextView"
                android:ems="10"
                android:text="Phone: "/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

and my activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

            Button loginButton;
            Button signUpButton;
            ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle instanceState) {
              super.onCreate(instanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.content_main);


              loginButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_login);
              loginButton.setTag(true);

              signUpButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_signup);

              viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.view_flipper);

              loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);
              signUpButton.setOnClickListener(this);

              updateTheViewBasedOnTag();
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.bt_login:
                  loginButton.setTag(true);
                  updateTheViewBasedOnTag();
                  viewFlipper.startFlipping();
                  break;
                case R.id.bt_signup:
                  signUpButton.setTag(true);
                  updateTheViewBasedOnTag();
                  break;
              }
            }

            private void updateTheViewBasedOnTag() {
              if((boolean)loginButton.getTag())
              {
                loginButton.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.selected_background));
                signUpButton.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.normal_background));
              }else
              {
                loginButton.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.selected_background));
                loginButton.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.normal_background));

              }
            }
          }
```

The

```
     viewFlipper.startFlipping();
```

doesn't seem to work correctly. I don't click the signup button but still the sign up for is shown. Also, the clicking of the buttons don't respond

What's wrong?

Thanks,

Theo.

Answer (score 0):

I am just trying to guess what is wrong with your code. You are setting the tag to true for one button and forgot to set the false for other button.

```
switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bt_login:
            loginButton.setTag(true);
            signUpButton.setTag(false);
            updateTheViewBasedOnTag();
            viewFlipper.startFlipping();
            break;
        case R.id.bt_signup:
            signUpButton.setTag(true);
            loginButton.setTag(false);
            updateTheViewBasedOnTag();
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Hello Purushotam Kumar. I tried that too, but still nothing.